# Using `NDSolve` with `Interpolation`

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

I don't think I full understand the nature of `NDSolve` or `Interpolation`. I can't understand why the second output doesn't match the first:

```
func1[{x0_, y0_}, T_] := Module[{}, X[t_] = t; Y[t_] = Sin[t];
nd = NDSolve[{Thread[{x'[t], y'[t]} == {X[t] - x[t], Y[t] - y[t]}/
Sqrt[(X[t] - x[t])^2 + (Y[t] - y[t])^2]], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x, y},  
{t, 0, T}];Table[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. nd[[1]]], {t, 0, T}]];

func2[{x0_, y0_}, T_] := Quiet@Module[{}, tableB = N@Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 1, 10, 1}];
X = Quiet[Interpolation /@ Table[Take[tableB[[All, 1]]], {k, 1, 10}]];
Y = Quiet[Interpolation /@ Table[Take[tableB[[All, 2]]], {k, 1, 10}]];
nd = NDSolve[{{Derivative[1][x][t] == (-x[t] + X[[t]][t])/
Sqrt[(-x[t] + X[[t]][t])^2 + (-y[t] + Y[[t]][t])^2], 
Derivative[1][y][t] == (-y[t] + Y[[t]][t])/Sqrt[(-x[t] + X[[t]][t])^2 + 
(-y[t] + Y[[t]][t])^2]}, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}];
Quiet@Table[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. nd[[1]]], {t, 0, T}]];

func1[{2, 2}, 5]
func2[{2, 2}, 5]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like there something odd going on with `Take[tableB[[All, 1]], y]` in your defs of `X` and `Y`? `Interpolation[tableB[[All, 1]], y]` gives you a somewhat sensible output (but not the same as the first, and a different set of error messages). Also, as far as I can tell you're defining `tableB` for `t = 1,... 100`, but then using its `Interpolation` for `t = 0,..., T`.

Comment: @aardvark2012 updated, so should make sense, but still no meaningful output

Comment: Could you clarify why you want to replace `t` and `Sin[t]` with `InterpolatingFunctions`? Your `X` function seems to be a very complicated way of writing `t`. `Interpolation[N@Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 1, 100, 1}]]` will give you an interpolated `Sin` function (over the domain `[1, 100]`) which you could use instead of `Y`. But could you explain why you'd want to interpolate `X = t`?

Comment: @aardvark2012 the data is variable - `Sin` is just a toy function. The actual data will be far less predictable, and will be cumulative - hence the complicated `X` and `Y` functions. If there is a numeric `FindRoot` or similar alternative, I'd be happy with that.

Comment: `X[[t]]` makes no sense if `t` is real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, I would recommend *not* using `Interpolation` here. A possible alternative using pure functions passed as arguments is

```
func4[{x0_, y0_}, T_, X_, Y_] := 
  Module[{nd},
   nd = First@
     NDSolve[{Thread[{x'[t], y'[t]} == {X[t] - x[t], Y[t] - y[t]}/
          Sqrt[(X[t] - x[t])^2 + (Y[t] - y[t])^2]], x[0] == x0, 
       y[0] == y0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}];
   Table[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. nd], {t, 0, T}]];
```

which you can then use as:

```
ListLinePlot[func4[{2, 2}, 20, # &, Sin]]
ListLinePlot[func4[{2, 2}, 20, Cos, Sin]]
ListLinePlot[func4[{2, 2}, 20, # Cos[#] &, Tan[2 # - 1] &]]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

If that's not possible, and you really need `Interpolation` for some reason, then there are two possibilities I can see, depending on what your goal is with `X` and `Y`. The first is that your input function is just `Y[t] = Sin[t]`, in which case interpolating `X[t] = t` conceptually problematic. The second is that your input functions are parameterized curves in `R^2`, such as `{X[t], Y[t]} = {Cos[t], Sin[t]}`, for example.

**Case I: `Y(t) = Sin(t)`**

The easy way of doing this (ie, without interpolating anything) would be

```
func[{x0_, y0_}, T_] := 
  Module[{nd}, 
   nd = First@
     NDSolve[{Thread[{x'[t], y'[t]} == {t - x[t], Sin[t] - y[t]}/
          Sqrt[(t - x[t])^2 + (Sin[t] - y[t])^2]], x[0] == x0, 
       y[0] == y0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}]; 
   Table[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. nd], {t, 0, T}]
   ];

ListLinePlot[func[{2, 2}, 20]]
```

[image]

To build in `Y[t]` as an `InterpolatingFunction` (and leave `X[t] = t`) just set `Y = Interpolation[tableB]`.

```
func2[{x0_, y0_}, T_] := 
  Module[{tableB = N@Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, T, 1}], nd, X, Y},
   Y = Interpolation[tableB];
   nd = First@
     NDSolve[{Thread[{x'[t], y'[t]} == {t - x[t], Y[t] - y[t]}/
          Sqrt[(t - x[t])^2 + (Y[t] - y[t])^2]], x[0] == x0, 
       y[0] == y0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}];
   Table[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. nd], {t, 0, T}]];

ListLinePlot[func2[{2, 2}, 20]]
```

[image]

which clearly agrees with the plot for the original `func`.

**Case II: `{X[t], Y[t]} = {Cos[t], Sin[t]}`**

For this case, the non-interpolating way would be

```
func[{x0_, y0_}, T_] := 
  Module[{nd}, 
   nd = First@
     NDSolve[{Thread[{x'[t], y'[t]} == {Cos[t] - x[t], Sin[t] - y[t]}/
          Sqrt[(Cos[t] - x[t])^2 + (Sin[t] - y[t])^2]], x[0] == x0, 
       y[0] == y0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}]; 
   Table[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. nd], {t, 0, T}]
   ];

ListLinePlot[func[{2, 2}, 20]]
```

[image]

The interpolating version is not much more complicated. Note how `tableB` is set up, and how `X` and `Y` are defined from it.

```
func3[{x0_, y0_}, T_] := 
  Module[{X, Y, nd, 
    tableB = N@Table[{t, Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, T, 1}]},
   X = Interpolation[tableB[[;; , {1, 2}]]];
   Y = Interpolation[tableB[[;; , {1, 3}]]];
   nd = First@
     NDSolve[{Thread[{x'[t], y'[t]} == {X[t] - x[t], Y[t] - y[t]}/
          Sqrt[(X[t] - x[t])^2 + (Y[t] - y[t])^2]], x[0] == x0, 
       y[0] == y0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}];
   Table[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. nd], {t, 0, T}]];

ListLinePlot[func3[{2, 2}, 17]]
```

[image]

Which, again, agrees with the simple version. However, note that I've taken `T = 17` and not `T = 20`. That's because this setup gets very slow very quickly.

Comment: great - thanks for your help. Will try it out for a range of data - I had a feeling it might get slow quickly.